# XML or Markdown documentation? Where to start as a new programmer

Tags: c#, xml, f#, markdown, documentation

I am a new programmer and I am learning to program with F# and currently learning about the documentation part. The F# built-in documentation syntax follows C# (XML).

My teacher wants us to write xml documentations, which I will of course learn. But on the side I read a lot of source codes which includes .md files instead, and have documentation online on GitHub for example.

Should I focus on learning the XML documentation method or should I focus on something else? 
Can someone hint me in a good direction on where to read a good and reliable guide on this?

Below is a short XML documentation (my first) I tried to write just documenting how a simple sum-function is working. Any kind of input would be greatly appreciated as well!

```
///<summary>Get the sum of numbers to n and with n included</summary>
///<example>
///     The code:
///   <code>
///         let sum(n : int) = 
/// 
///              let mutable result: int = 0
///              let mutable i     : int = 0
/// 
///              while i < n do
/// 
///                  i <- i + 1
///                  result <- result + i
/// 
///          result 
///   </code>
///</example>
///
///<remarks>Input:
///   <code>
///         printfn "Sum af 1 + 2 + ... + n = %i" (sum(4)) 
///  </code>   
///</remarks>
///<returns>Sum af 1 + 2 + ... + n = 10</returns>
///<param name="n"> Natural number, n > 0 n <> real numbers </param>




let sum(n : int) = 

    let mutable result: int = 0
    let mutable i     : int = 0

    while i < n do

        i <- i + 1
        result <- result + i

    result // result of sum of n

printfn "Sum af 1 + 2 + ... + n = %i" (sum(4))
```

Comment: StackOverflow discourages questions about technology selection, for the very good reason that you really need more than a paragraph or two of information to make a reasoned recommendation in favour of one technology over another. Clearly there's always a good argument for "do what everyone else in your community does", because that will tend to mean good support from tools, less re-training of staff, and so on. Generally, Markdown is optimized for ease of authoring, whereas XML is optimized for maximum reusability of content, and that might affect your decision.

Comment: To add to @MichaelKay's comment, the XML comments will add context if you are using Visual Studio to edit the F# source files when intellisense is triggered. XML comments can also be easily converted to HTML documentation using automated tools. See https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/02/21/vs-dotnet-code-documentation-tools-roundup.aspx That being said markdown is natively rendered in Github, so for User Documentation it can be easier to publish if written in markdown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lot of professional F# projects use the [FSharp.Formatting library](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Formatting/), which allows you to write Markdown instead of XML in the "XML documentation" comments (that is, the `///` comments). It can be a little bit tricky to set up FSharp.Formatting if you're just learning F#, so my recommendation would be to use something like the [ProjectScaffold template](https://github.com/fsprojects/ProjectScaffold): you clone the https://github.com/fsprojects/ProjectScaffold repository, then run `build.sh` (or `build.cmd` if you're on Windows) and answer a few questions like the name of your project. (And then you should rename the folder from ProjectScaffold to something that matches the name of your project). From that point on, running `build.sh` or `build.cmd` will take the `///` comments in your project, run them through FSharp.Formatting, and convert them to good HTML documentation (to put online) *and* good XML documentation for use in other tools.

For now, of course, you should follow your teacher's instructions. But at the same time, you should also get familiar with FSharp.Formatting (and I *highly* recommend using something like ProjectScaffold for that purpose rather than trying to set it up on your own). Then once you know it works, you can ask your teacher whether using FSharp.Formatting and Markdown would be acceptable, and show him the results.

Comment: Thanks rmunn! I'll follow my teachers instructions of course but I will on the side look into ProjectScaffold as you suggest.

Comment: I wanted to write you a PM rmunn for helping out both here and with my other subjects on F#. You truly helped me today.
I would love watching F# video lectures from you and read guides by you. Your explainations are very understandable. You seem to know a lot about the language and I feel there is a lack of good user-friendly guides out there!

Comment: @jubibanna - The best guide to F# is https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/ by Scott Wlaschin. There are other guides like https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming, but I've found that https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/ is by far the best. I'd start there.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best resouce to learn about markdown is: https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/.

You can use markdown as documentation, xml should not be used to create documentation.

Comment: Something to consider strongly is that the documentation you provide should add value.  Tell things that reading the code cannot communicate. If the comments repeat the code they will become either a maintenance burden or a lie eventually

Comment: Yes add documentation is good, but I think by using xml probably is not the best, instead you should to use by example for java JavaDoc

Comment: @JavierLópezLópez - For F#, XMLDoc [is the standard officially recommended by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/xml-documentation). However, the unofficial standard is to use Markdown instead and use [FSharp.Formatting](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Formatting/) to convert the Markdown to XMLDoc format. So the F# equivalent of JavaDoc that you mentioned is either XML or Markdown.

Comment: I see, then it is my fail, I never had worked on F#, then if is the case XML still being valid format to create comments :)